# Why is there a spacing between the window-border and a list(item)?

Tags: html, css, list, spacing

I have been searching endlessly to why there is an extra spacing between my window-border and the first item of a simple menu, build with a list. 
I tried everything I could find on the web, but still there is this extra spacing...

Does anyone have an idea or suggestion?

[The page is to be seen here.](http://www.antwerpporttours.com/new/)

The HTML code is:

```
<body>

<div class="indexblock">
        <div id="menu">

            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Tours</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">B2B</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Scholen</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Nl/En</a></li>
            </ul>

        </div>
</div>



<div class="block">
    <div id="one">
        <div id="frame">            

<h1> dit is een titel </h1>
<p> dit is heel wat tekst dit is heel wat tekst dit is heel wat tekst 
dit is heel wat tekst dit is heel wat tekst dit is heel wat tekst dit is heel wat tekst 
dit is heel wat tekst dit is heel wat tekst dit is heel wat tekst dit is heel wat tekst 
dit is heel wat tekst dit is heel wat tekst dit is heel wat tekst </p>

<h1> Dit is een tussentitel </h1>

<p> dit is heel wat tekst dit is heel wat tekst dit is heel wat tekst 
dit is heel wat tekst dit is heel wat tekst dit is heel wat tekst dit is heel wat tekst 
dit is heel wat tekst dit is heel wat tekst dit is heel wat tekst dit is heel wat tekst 
dit is heel wat tekst dit is heel wat tekst dit is heel wat tekst </p>

<p class="filled"> Dit is een ondertittel </p>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The css:

```
html, body
{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
html
{
    height: 100%;
}

body
{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 1.4;
    position: relative;
    background: url(../img/background.jpg) fixed no-repeat;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    font-family:"helvetica";
    font-color:#ff6633 !important;
}

#block{
    float:center;
    margin-top: 50px;
    margin-left: auto; 
    margin-right: auto;
    background:#fff;
    width:80%;
    display:block;
    opacity:0.9;
    position:relative;
    overflow:hidden;
    moz-border-radius: 10px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
}

#indexblock{
    float:center;
    margin-top: 50px;
    margin-left: auto; 
    margin-right: auto;
    width:80%;
    display:block;
    opacity:0.9;
    position:relative;
    overflow:hidden;
}

#menu {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 80%;
    display: table;
    overflow: hidden; 
    moz-border-radius: 7px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 7px;
    border-radius: 7px;
    opacity:0.9;
}
#menu li {
    display: inline;
    height: 25px;
    margin: 0;
    font-size: 18px;
}
#menu li:first-child {
    padding-left: 0px;
}
#menu li a {
    width: 80%;
    display: inline;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 10px; 
    margin: 0;
    line-height: 50px;
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: #fff;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #ff6633;
    moz-border-radius: 10px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    opacity:0.9;
    border-color:#ff6633;
    border-style:solid;
    border-width:3px;
    }

#menu li a:hover {
    background-color: #16375b;
    color: #fff;
    border-color:#fff;
}
```

Comment: browsers gives default styles for some the elements for `ul` `padding` is given just add `#menu ul { padding:0}` it will fix the issue

Comment: you should know more about [reset.css](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/)

Comment: possible duplicate of [remove white space on ul with css](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17129891/remove-white-space-on-ul-with-css)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default there is margin and padding on the `<ul>`tag (unordered list).

Simply add the following code to your stylesheet:

```
#menu ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Oh I knew it had to be something simple... 
I feel like I have been looking for my carkeys while I was holding hem; the code worked. Thanks!

Comment: Haha, nice analogy. You should consider using some sort of reset in the future, it will make your life as lot easier! The reset I personally use and is extremely popular is the [meyerweb reset](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/), check it out.